# C++ 2 Player Dice Game

Tags: c++, dice

Player A rolls
m
dice, while Player B rolls
m
+ 1 dice. If Player A rolls
a n
's and
Player B rolls
b n's, then Player A wins if
a > b
. Otherwise, Player A rolls up to
k
of the
m
dice (the ones not showing
n) to roll again. If
a'
of these are
n's then Player A wins if
a
+
a' > b
. If
a + a' <= b, then Player B wins.

So I am wondering if I did what I wrote is correct. Along with the following:

I want to run the program where for each value of m,k and q 10000 times and calculate the number of times Player B wins. Along with this I want to be able to loop the values through different values of m,k and q to 10, 10, 15, respectively.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h> // NULL
#include <stdlib.h> // srand, rand
#include <time.h> // time
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

void cheddar();

int main(){
  cheddar();
}

void cheddar(){
  int m = 3;
  int n = 6;
  int k = 1;
  int q = 6; 
  int dicerolledA = m;
  int dicerolledB = m+1;
  int dicererolled = k;
  int diceA[20];
  int diceB[20];
  int countnA = 0;
  int countnB = 0;
  int awins = 0;
  int bwins = 0;
  int totalcount = 1;
  srand(time(0));
  //while (totalcount <= 10000){
    for(int i=dicerolledA-1;i>=0;i--){
      diceA[i]=rand()%q+1;
      //cout << diceA[i] << ' ';
      if (diceA[i] == n){
        countnA++;
      }
    }
    //cout << endl;
    for(int i=dicerolledB-1;i>=0;i--){
      diceB[i]=rand()%q+1;
      //cout << diceB[i] << ' ';
      if (diceB[i] == 6){
        countnB++;
      }
    }
    //cout << endl;
    if(countnB >= countnA){
      for(int i=dicererolled-1;i>=0;i--){
        diceA[i] = rand()%q+1;
        //cout << diceA[i];
        if(diceA[i] == n){
          countnA++;
        }
      }
      //cout << endl;
      if(countnB >= countnA){
        bwins++;
      }
      else{
        awins++;
      }
    }
    else if (countnA > countnB){
      awins++;
    }
    totalcount++;
    dicerolledA = m;
    dicerolledB = m+1;
    dicererolled = k;
    countnA = 0;
    countnB = 0;
  //}
  cout << bwins << ' ';
  awins = 0;
  bwins = 0;
  totalcount = 1;
}
```

Comment: So you wrote a program and wondering what it will do?  Why not just run it?  Or are you afraid that if you do run it, it may have (gasp) bugs that you will need to fix?

Comment: No, I am wondering how to loop the program for various m, k and q variables. The program runs correctly

Comment: `So I am wondering if I did what I wrote is correct`  So what is this supposed to mean?

Comment: You seem to know how to construct a loop. Are you comfortable with functions that take arguments?

Comment: @Beta Yes I am comfortable with that

Comment: @PaulMckenzie I wrote one thing when I meant how would i go about this statement `Player A rolls up to k of the m dice (the ones not showing n) to roll again`.

Answer (score 2):

Start with first creating a function called cheddar() with the requisite parameters.

```
void cheddar(int m, int k, int q);
int main()
{
   int mValue, kValue, qValue;
   //...
   cheddar(mValue, kValue, qValue);
}

void cheddar(int m, int k, int q)
{
   // function
}
```

Once you are comfortable with calling a function, then go on to writing a loop that calls this function using the various values.